# No records getting pulled for previous day records using SYSDATE - ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I have columns *INSERT_TIME* and *UPDATE_TIME* in my table of `Date` datatype. Both of columns which now holds a value *24-FEB-2019* (for 10 records).

I now use this query to pick those 10 records using:

```
SELECT /*+parallel(8)*/ * 
FROM   SCHEMA.table1 
WHERE  (insert_time = Trunc(To_date(sysdate)) - 1 ) 
        OR (update_time = Trunc(To_date(sysdate)) - 1 ) 
           AND table1_zipcode NOT IN(SELECT zipcode 
                                     FROM   SCHEMA.table2);
```

This query is not picking the records and returns an empty result.

I have also modified the query like:

```
SELECT /*+parallel(8)*/ * 
FROM   SCHEMA.table 
WHERE  ( insert_time = Trunc(sysdate) - 1 ) 
        OR ( update_time = Trunc(sysdate) - 1 ) 
           AND table1_zipcode NOT IN(SELECT zipcode 
                                     FROM   SCHEMA.table2);
```

and

```
SELECT /*+parallel(8)*/ * 
FROM   SCHEMA.table 
WHERE  ( insert_time = sysdate - 1 ) 
        OR ( update_time = sysdate) - 1 ) 
           AND table1_zipcode NOT IN(SELECT zipcode 
                                     FROM   SCHEMA.table2);
```

But nothing seems to work. Am I missing something? Can someone please help?

Comment: Do the record really hold a date value representing 24-FEB-2019 - that is, exactly midnight on that day? Or are they really different times throughout that day, as the column name suggests? (Your client might just be showing you that date part - but if you change the NLS settings, or use `to_char(insert_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` you'll see the full dates and times...)

Comment: Yes Alex. It is in '2019-02-24 06:27:45'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle date values, including [`sysdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYSDATE.html), include the time. Sometimes that is midnight for all rows, when the column is only intended to capture the date part. In your case that seems not to be the case, and you'll have times throughout the day. (That is suggested by the column names, but even more so by the fact you aren't currently getting any matches.)

If your client is showing you the values as 24-FEB-2019 then you can't tell what time portion they have; you can change the client or NLS settings, or specify the full date/time format model as part of the query with `to_char(insert_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`.

When you do:

```
(insert_time = Trunc(To_date(sysdate)) - 1 )
```

you are implicitly converting `sysdate` from a date to a string, using your current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, and then implicitly converting it back to a date using the same format model. Given your reference to 24-FEB-2019 that model is DD-MON-YYYY, which means you're effectively losing the time portion in that conversion - the `to_date()` will give you the starting date at midnight. (Someone else running with different NLS settings might not see what effect though.) The `trunc()` then sets the time to midnight, which at that point isn't actually doing anything with your NLS settings. And then you subtract a day.

When you do:

```
( insert_time = Trunc(sysdate) - 1 )
```

you're skipping the conversion to and from a string, and this time it's the `trunc()` that does set the time portion to midnight.

In both cases you're then looking records which are exactly midnight - i.e. where `insert_time` is exactly 2019-02-24 00:00:00. As you aren't finding any rows, none of your table data on that date is at exactly midnight, which probably isn't surprising.

When you do:

```
( insert_time = sysdate - 1 )
```

you aren't setting the time portion to midnight any more, but that means if you ran this today at say 15:51:37 then you would only match rows where `inert_time` was exactly 2019-02-24 15:15:37, which is possible but unlikely if you only have 10 rows that day. Each execution checks a different time, so one might get lucky eventually...

If you want to find rows at any time yesterday you can do:

```
(insert_time >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 and insert_time < trunc(sysdate))
```

which looks for anything at or after midnight yesterday (sysdate -1), but also earlier than midnight today. And the same for `update_time`, with appropriate parentheses to control the logic evaluation.

```
SELECT /*+parallel(8)*/ * 
FROM   SCHEMA.table1 
WHERE  (
            (insert_time >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 AND insert_time < trunc(sysdate)) 
         OR (update_time >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 AND update_time < trunc(sysdate))
       )
AND table1_zipcode NOT IN(SELECT zipcode FROM SCHEMA.table2);
```

Comment: Great Explanation Alex. ! So, can I use two values of timestamp datatype to check if this `to_char(insert_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` value lies between them?

Comment: The `to_char()` is only to display the value in full. Except for final display you should leave things in their native data type, and compare them as such. Your columns are dates (which have date and time, down to seconds) not timestamps (which can also have fractional seconds and/or time zones). And `sysdate`, `trunc(sysdate)` and `trunc(sysdate) - 1` are all also dates. Does the last query in my answer not do what you need?

Comment: Yes. That answers my need. :) Thanks a ton.